# Understanding the best approach to create a widget in AngularJS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

I just came across a cool website [tawk](https://www.tawk.to/), which provides some really great features. [In this page](https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/getting-started/adding-a-widget-to-your-website/), they have explained a simple way to integrate their widget by adding few lines of JS code:

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, 
       Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
   (function(){
     var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     s1.async=true;
     s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/58d90960f97dd14875f5a534/default';
     s1.charset='UTF-8';
     s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
     s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
   })();
 </script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

I [googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=create%20site%20widgets%20angularJS&oq=create%20site%20widgets%20angularJS&gs_l=serp.3...36564.39342.0.40211.5.5.0.0.0.0.123.493.3j2.5.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.1.104...0i30k1j0i8i30k1.jZAhKZcqTp4) the same for AngularJS or JavaScript but didnt get anything to create similar usability widgets. Can someone please provide any good live example / tutorials for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make a very simple widget with the simplest way to include it in your page.

First create an html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Widget Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Widget Demo</h1>
    <p>A clock widget will be inserted next:</p>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
    <p>And a new one here:</p>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

We are going to create a clock widget, and the way to include it will be to adding `<script src="clock.js"></script>` right where you want it to appear.

Now lets write the widget code part, create clock.js:

```
new class {

    constructor() {
        document.write("<div class='Clock'></div>");
        const clocks = document.querySelectorAll(".Clock");
        this.element = clocks[clocks.length - 1];

        this.element.style.width = "200px";
        this.element.style.lineHeight = "80px";
        this.element.style.textAlign = "center";
        this.element.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
        this.element.style.fontSize = "35px";
        this.element.style.background = "#ddd";
        this.element.style.borderRadius = "15px";

        this.draw();
        setInterval(this.draw.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    draw() {
        this.element.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    }

}
```

Lets check this part by part:

`new class {` <- each time clock.js is executed a new object of the following class will be created.

Now, we need to create an element for our widget and place it in the page:

```
document.write("<div class='Clock'></div>");
const clocks = document.querySelectorAll(".Clock");
this.element = clocks[clocks.length - 1];
```

There are multiple ways to do this, I have just opted for the shortest one. So, `document.write` will insert html code right after the script tag currently being executed. So, I'm inserting text that will create a div element. In order to be able to select it and keep using it from Javascript, I have added to it a .Clock class, so I can select all the clocks with querySelectorAll. Finally, I store the last one of them, that is the one I have just create as my new object's element.

This is the only a bit tricky part of the process, other than that, there is nothing special, but lets keep checking:

```
    this.element.style.width = "200px";
    this.element.style.lineHeight = "80px";
    this.element.style.textAlign = "center";
    this.element.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
    this.element.style.fontSize = "35px";
    this.element.style.background = "#ddd";
    this.element.style.borderRadius = "15px";
```

Just styling the element. We don't have a css file or a html file, so we are creating everything with javascript.

```
    this.draw();
    setInterval(this.draw.bind(this), 1000);
```

I will be calling the draw function for the first time, and then each second to update the clock's text with the current time:

```
draw () {
    this.element.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}
```

And... that's it! You should not load css files because they can cause css collisions with the page that is loading it, but if you feel you really need to load css, you can do it by inserting with javascript a  element into the document's  and it will load. If you want to have more than a single javascript file, you should bundle them into a single one server side, but if you really need to do it on the client side, you could do it the same as the code you posted: create a script file and add it the DOM. There are other ways, but that method is the simplest. And if you wanted to include some parts of html from other file, it would be possible too, but again better embed everything into a single .js, it would be compact and fast to load.

Comment: Oh... I forgot to mention that you can also use an iframe. Without the iframe you can have some control over the widget, like setting some css border on the widget, with iframe not... and there might be some more differences...

Comment: can u plz provide a working plunker. The syntax of clock.js is not proper. It would be helpful to have a plunker

Comment: I have uploaded it to my own server, I created the files from copy/pasting the code here: http://romancortes.com/widget-demo/

Comment: I have tried it and it is working in latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera. If it fails in the browser you are using, please tell me which one is it, version and OS

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see the clock in the browser, The error is in Netbeans IDE intellisense. I'll ignore it for now.

Comment: Ah, ok... Maybe it is not up to date with Javascript? Let me write a version with old style Javascript, give me a second...

Comment: I'm trying to add the code for older browsers, but it doesn't allow me to do the edit... just says error, but not why, so adding a new answer for it

Answer (score 0):

A version of clock.js for older browsers:

```
if (!Clock) {
    function Clock() {
        document.write("<div class='Clock'></div>");
        const clocks = document.querySelectorAll(".Clock");
        this.element = clocks[clocks.length - 1];

        this.element.style.width = "200px";
        this.element.style.lineHeight = "80px";
        this.element.style.textAlign = "center";
        this.element.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
        this.element.style.fontSize = "35px";
        this.element.style.background = "#ddd";
        this.element.style.borderRadius = "15px";

        this.draw();
        setInterval(this.draw.bind(this), 1000);
    }
    Clock.prototype.draw = function () {
        this.element.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }
}
new Clock();
```

Added here instead of editing the previous answer because I'm getting an error when trying to editing. Maybe post too long?

Comment: Why  replacing with `s1.src='clock.js';` doesnt work. https://plnkr.co/edit/ivD3MHpoecG654dK1SkO?p=preview

Comment: document.write is not working as expected in that case.

Comment: You need to use a method for creating the element and attaching it to the DOM that works. As I told you, in my example I showed you the easiest way as possible, but if you modify it (and I'm not sure why you want to modify it like that), then you might need to do new changes

Comment: And just to clarify, the code you provided is loading dynamically a javascript file by creating and attaching a script tag. If you don't have a specific reason to do that, then you don't have to.

Comment: Oh and, in my examples, what I'm trying to achieve is to insert the widget at the position you place the script, that in some cases can be very interesting, but it is not needed. You can just load a script and the script can wait for the page to load and just attach itself to the top of the page as a floating widget, for example. In fact... let's do a floating widget!

Comment: I added a second example: http://romancortes.com/widget-demo/  This doesn't use document.write, so it will work as you want. Instead of inserting the widget at the position of the script, it will always add the widget at the top of the document's body

Comment: Thats very helpful. Can you help me understand any possible reason why `tawk.to` would load JS file in such a manner. Also, can u suggest me some topics to understand such type of examples ? other than this , your answers are extremely help. Many thanks

Comment: I see that they are doing this: Tawk_LoadStart=new Date(); With it, they can compute, for example, how long does it take since the browser is about to start loading the js file and after it is loaded, when the js file just started executing. I don't know why they use it, maybe they send that data back to their servers to know how the system is working... or maybe not. No idea.

Comment: You know, there are no guidelines or right or wrong ways to do it... you can use all the browser capabilities to develop your purpose. Anything that works. So, what Tawk is doing is not as important as what do you need. For example, Youtube uses an iframe to embed videos. The iframe is good for them. Depending on what you are doing an iframe can have advantages or disadvantages. It provides you isolation and encapsulation. The iframe, loaded from a different domain, can't access the parent page, and the page can't access the iframe.

Comment: Then suppose that there is a widget that the user should be able to resize. If it were in an iframe, the widget can't resize the iframe because the iframe is in the parent page, and it can't access it. In that case, you need the js loading method, that allows access to the page

Comment: Oh and, everything doesn't need to be black or white. You could, for example, add a bit of code for resizing the iframe in the code you tell the user to copy / paste.